# JSOUP : Retain specific tags

Tags: android, jsoup

Any way we could retain specific tags and remove the rest from a node.
Like

```
<li>my name is <a>this is link</a>
  <li>again bullet</li>
</li>
```

In this i want to remove the nested li tag and retain just a tag.

How would I do it using jsoup  /.

Comment: Do you want to keep the `<a>this is link</a>` as well?

Comment: Please provide an example what the exact string you want to retain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Select the tags you want to remove and ask Jsoup to remove them.*

With the example in your post, here is how the phrase below can be translated:

```
String html = "<li>my name is <a>this is link</a>  <li>again bullet</li></li>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

System.out.println("\nBEFORE:\n" + doc);

doc.select("li ~ li").remove();

System.out.println("\nAFTER:\n" + doc);
```

Note that the original html code is invalid. This is why Jsoup moves out the nested `li` tag.

#### OUTPUT

```
BEFORE:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <li>my name is <a>this is link</a> </li>
  <li>again bullet</li>
 </body>
</html>

AFTER:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <li>my name is <a>this is link</a> </li>
 </body>
</html>
```